# How to get the most common class among elements

Tags: ruby

How can I get the most common data type (i.e. class) among the elements of an array? For example, for this array:

```
array = [nil, "string", 1, 3, 0.234, 25, "hot potato"]
```

`Integer` should be returned since it's the most common class.

Comment: By data type you mean the element's class?

Comment: @Stefan I believe so (I used data type just in case class meant something more specific that I wasn't aware of). Looks like class is what I meant (have edited question / title to reflect)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
array.group_by(&:class).max_by{|k, v| v.length}.first
# => Integer
```

Answer (score 4):

```
array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e.class] += 1 }.
      max_by(&:last).
      first
        #=> Integer
```

the first step being

```
array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e.class] += 1 }
  #=> {NilClass=>1, String=>2, Integer=>3, Float=>1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following can also work,

```
array.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v.class] += 1; h }.max_by(&:last).first
```

Comment: This will call `count` for each element, thus traversing the array multiple times.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks, correction done, query changed which take less time to execute!

Comment: @Stefan I checked above with benchmark, worked great but I am curious/unclear to know that how ` h[:z] += 1` works for `h = Hash.new(0)` but not for `h = {}`

Comment: If you are concerned with the speed, try with a much larger array (where the speed should actually matter in real life), for example `array * 100000`, and see what happens.

Comment: @ray `h[:z] += 1` is short for `h[:z] = h[:z] + 1`. For an empty hash without a default value, this becomes `h[:z] = nil + 1`.

Comment: @Stefan but `h = Hash.new(0)` also create empty hash so why worked for it? It worked for `h[<any_key>] + 1`.

Comment: @ray but it has a default value of `0` so `h[:z] = h[:z] + 1` becomes `h[:z] = 0 + 1` on the first invocation.

Comment: @sawa yes agreed, I got your point too. In some cases, performance varies when data expands, above is checked for small array, may vary for bigger one.

Comment: You have to run each benchmark multiple times to get a meaningful result. Wrap each test in `50_000.times { ... }` and see what happens. (`inject` and `each_with_object` should be almost identical and `group_by` should be slightly faster)

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for giving time! it will be appreciated, if you provide any link to guide how to use benchmark effectively!

Comment: `'each_by_object'` should be `...max_by(&:last)`, not `...max_by()`. I suggest you add `require 'benchmark'`.

Comment: @sawa, for `array*100000`, the "total" (or "real") results are as follows: "group_by": 0.27; "each_with_object": 0.49; "inject": 0.49.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks prof., I suspect it will vary behaviour for small and big data (like happen for sorting algo.), I will update to remove unnecessary benchmark in answer!